# Inherit already instantiated class

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

I have a base class that contains a method (model detect) to detect some equipment and return the model number.
Based on this model number the module will return the correct subclass for the model number.

All of the calls to the equipment use a handle. The handle for any subclass needs to be the same handle as the one created in the base class.

The issue I am running into is that to inherit the variables (specifically self.handle) from base class into a subclass, i need to execute the function from the base class (in this case model detect), using self.model_detect().

If i do this it tries to create a handle to the equipment which already has an open handle (because model_detect is getting run twice).

In essence, i want to run model detect once and then be able to access self.handle in the subclasses:

```
def equip_detect():
    # detect equipment model and return correct sub class
    equip_class=base_class()
    handle = equip_class.model_detect()

    if equip_class.model==1:
        return sub_class1(handle)

    elif equip_class.model==2:
        return sub_class2(handle)
    else:
        print('Equipment not detected')


class base_class:
    def __init__(self):
        print('base_class_init')
        self.var=1

    def model_detect(self):
        print('get equipment handle, should be run only once')
        # Setup equipment handle: Dummy equipment handle
        self.handle=12345
        # Detect model type: Dummy model
        self.model=1
        print ('Model detected: %s' % self.model)
        return self.handle


class sub_class1(base_class):
    # inherit base class including self.handle
    def __init__(self, handle):
        self.var2='test_subclass1'
##        self.model_detect()
        print(handle)

    def specific_functions_here(self):
        print('model 1 code here')

class sub_class2(base_class):
    # inherit base class including self.handle
    def __init__(self, handle):
        self.var2='test_subclass2'
        print(handle)

    def specific_functions_here(self):
        print('model 2 code here')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    myclass=equip_detect()
    myclass.specific_functions_here()
```

I got around it by returning the handle from the model detect function and adding an argument into each sub class.

I cant help thinking I am not really using inheritance here. Is there a cleaner (more pythonic) way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need a factory pattern  -
the easiest way there would be to have `model_detect` independent of the instance - as a classmethod or staticmethod, or even a stand-alone function. Threfore, only after you have the model to set you instantiated the target class.

If "model_detect" depends on state set in `__init__` to run, this can be less clean. If the state set is just some ID or access path for your devices, I'd say you to just send those as a parameter. If it is more complicated than that, them, maybe, inheritance is not the best pattern for you.

So, the simplest idea is:

```
def model_detect(device_id):
    print('get equipment handle, should be run only once')
    # Setup equipment handle: Dummy equipment handle
    handle=12345
    # Detect model type: Dummy model
    model=1
    print (f'Model detected: {model}')
    return handle, model

def equip_detect(equip_id):
    # detect equipment model and return correct sub class
    handle, model = model_detect(equip_id)
    
    if model==1:
        return sub_class1(handle)

    elif model==2:
        return sub_class2(handle)
    else:
        print('Equipment not detected')
        
...

class sub_class1(base_class):
    # Model hard coded as class attribute
    model = 1
    def __init__(self, handle):
        # model available here as self.model
    ...

class sub_class2(base_class):
    model = 2
    ...
```

This wold work equally well if "model_detect" be placed as a "classmethod" or a "staticmethod": it just can't be run as an instance method unless you want to instantiate the class twice.

For the record: Python *would* allow the instace's class to be changed once the model is detected. It an be done by simply setting the `__class__` attribute on the instance.  **This is not and oficial pattern** nor had I ever seem anyone recommending it outside of playing code and experimentations, but it would fit your needs, and, if done properly, would work there with no issues.

In that case, `detect_model` could set the class once it does its job, and from that point on, all methods and class attrbitutes for the instance will be those of the target class. All code-linting and static tools in the Python echo-system would blink red lights everywhere:

```py
class base_class:
    def __init__(self):
        print('base_class_init')
        self.var=1
        self.model_detect()

class auto_model(base_class):
    def model_detect(self):
        # Setup equipment handle: Dummy equipment handle
        self.handle=12345
        self.model=1
        self.__class__ = classmap[self.model]
        return self.handle


class sub_class1(base_class):

    def specific_functions_here(self):
        print('model 1 code here')


class sub_class2(base_class):

    def specific_functions_here(self):
        print('model 2 code here')
        
        
classmap = {
    1: sub_class1,
    2: sub_class2
}
```

(The classmap thing is just a shorter way to write your `if model==x: yyyy` pattern)
In this way you would not even need the `equip_detect` function to determine the class, you instantiate the  `auto_model`, and it transforms itself into the proper class once model_detect is run.

Now, if you want a tradicional OO approach, *and* there is a lot of state set in the `__init__` code, that would make it unwieldy to call `model_detect` without instance data, I'd split your classes in 2 hierarchies: on that features model_detect, and can set `self.model`, and another that implements model specific code - this second hierarchy would then *contain a reference*  instead of inherit the instance that can detect the model. In this approach, the factory function is needed:

```
def equip_detect(some_id):
    equip_core = generic_equip(some_id)
    if device.model == 1:
        equip = sub_class1(device)
    ...
    
    return equip


class generic_equip:
    def __init__(...):
        ...
    def model_detect(self, ...):
        ...
        self.model = X
        self.handler = Y
        
class device_base:
    def __init__(self, equip_core):
        self.equip_core = equip_core
        
    # optional property. Otherwise, always use instance.equip_core.handler
    @property
    def handler(self):
        return self.equip_core.handler
    
    
class sub_class1(device_base):
    def especific_function(self):
        ....
```

For a large code base, I'd favor this last approach.